# Post issues to Bitbucket via Python requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests, bitbucket

I'm trying to post issues to bitbucket via their api. If I understand correctly it seems I can go the basic authentication route rather than OAuth. When making the request, though, when *print(r.status_code)* runs I'm getting a 400 code back in the terminal. The problem seems to be in either the json (which I doubt) or the authentication.

I'm running this in a django project and my code is as follows:

**views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    getUser = request.user
    form = IssueForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        data = {"priority": "major", "title": "title", "kind": "bug", "content": "content"} 

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
        r = requests.post('https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{my_username}/{my_repo}/issues/', headers=headers, json=data, auth=({username},{password}))
        print(r.status_code)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/main/")

    else:
        form = IssueForm()


    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "issue_form.html", context)
```

Possibly basic authentication is not allowed for posting issues and instead OAuth is necessary? However, I have not found any documentation that has indicated as such. Or perhaps there is a way to go about implementing OAuth1 via python requests in Django?

Username, repo, and password are filled in accordingly. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Took the auth=({username},{password}) out and got a 401 as opposed to a 400 error with them in. Seems to be a problem with the data but I'm not quite sure what's wrong with the formatting of the data. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: auth problem would be 401, but 400 you will get if your input data is invalid according to the expected https://http.cat/400 ...check *data*, there is something wrong or missing.

Comment: print r.text may they give you details

Comment: oha, got a 400 on instagram with this text: Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter.

Comment: ahh, ended up getting `400
<ul class="errorlist"><li>title<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` so it is a problem with my data. Thanks for your help, I'll have too look into this a little more!

Answer (score 0):

Reading always helps, kids. I was able to just install `BitBucket-API` and use it along with the help of this documentation to post my issues.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/bitbucket-api/latest/bitbucket-api.pdf

code ended up looking like:

    `bb = Bitbucket('username', 'password', repo_name_or_slug="REPOSLUG")
    success, result = bb.issue.create(
        title=u'title',
        content=u'content',
        responsible=bb.username,
        status=u'new',
        kind=u'kind')`

Comment: This solves the problem with a different library but doesn't provide a solution for posting issues with `requests` module.